# Resizing Page Elements based on Window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, dimensions

**Problem:**
My Client wants me to create a launch webpage for his product such that there should be no scroll on the page, be any browser or window dimensions.

**Doubt:** Is this possible using CSS and Javascript?

**Some Early Diagnosis:** This might be a little similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274401/dynamically-resizing-the-height-of-div-based-upon-the-size-resolution-of-users-m) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838137/jquery-change-height-based-on-browser-size-resize) but the difference is that I want to resize the dimensions of each and every element in a particular ratio and not just adjust the height of a parent DIV.

**So, the statement:** I need to change the dimensions of each and every element (images, divs, text ... all) based on a ratio between the **(current window size and a reference window size)**. Perhaps Javascript might have a cure for this?

**Question:** How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `height` and `width` of `<html>` and `<body>` to `100%`, `overflow` to `hidden` and use [percentages](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#percentage-units) for `left`, `top`, `width` and `height` of elements:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=UTF-8>
  <title>Proportional resizing</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    div {
      position: absolute;
      left: 30%;
      top: 20%;
      width: 40%;
      height: 30%;
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>divthing</div>
</body>
</html>
```

These percentages are relative to the [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block), which is, in this case `<body>`.

---

*Update:* To answer another question: scaling of background images is almost not supported yet. When the CSS 3 [`background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) property gains ground (see [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29#cite_ref-spec-back-borders_19-1)), things will be easier. For now, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background/388817#388817) (yes, that means: more markup).

Comment: thats surely possibble, but would it take care that I want to display the background of the DIV as a whole? coz, on small window, background would be cutoff, and large window it would repeat... :)

Comment: Also, since I have CSS-ified most of the page, before this special request from my client dropped in, so i was hoping if there existed a solution which would not make me change the CSS again. ;) ;)

Comment: @Orange – You mean, you want the background to be scaled to the whole size of the `div`?

Comment: @Orange – Regarding your second remark: no, you *almost* can't do this without changing your CSS and perhaps your HTML structure, too. This kind of presentational things are closely related to the markup and CSS. The only way of doing this without changing your HTML or at least your CSS, is indeed using JavaScript. But you really, really don't want to do this that way, you shouldn't hassle around with the positions of all elements in JavaScript (and JavaScript may be turned off or blocked in your visitor's browser).

Comment: @marcel yeah, scaling is needed. :'( . . . Although a JS solution could also help even though I can try spending time for readjustment in CSS, its just that time is short. :)

Comment: @Orange – Though I understand your position and you'll not always be able to improve things, consider this: “before this special request from my client dropped in” and “time is short”. As it is a ‘special request’, seemingly not known when you both made decisions about the site, you have a good ground to ask more time to redesign it.

Comment: @marcel ah.. surely. ;) although that updated link in the answer is good too. Thanks a lot btw for all of this. :)